# Uniqueness of Brouwer fixed point theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am reading Brouwer’s fixed point thereom. Does the uniqueness holds in Brouwers theorem i.e.

> Is it true that every non identity continuous map $f: D \to D$ has unique fixed point?

D- closed unit disc

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: No, not even true in one dimension.

Comment: Just consider the identity function  $f(x)=x$ and every point is the fixed point so the uniqueness generally does not hold.

Comment: @J1U, the question rules out the identity.

Comment: @Laz Oh I missed that part. But even then, one can just modify the identity map continuously so that the function has multiple fixed points.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I did below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x,y)=(x,-y)$. It maps the disk onto itself, is not the identity, and has a continuum of fixed points of the form $(x,0)$.